# How to print result of shell script in CMake?

Tags: shell, printing, cmake, environment-variables

If I want to check currently exported environment variables, I do this in shell.

```
export
```

In CMake, I do this to print something.

```
MESSAGE ("This is message.")
```

How can I print former one with CMake?

I know that CMake is stand for cross-platform building, anyway when debugging something I need to check raw values. So I need this.

Comment: old make had a cmd-line arg (maybe -v or -x) that showed all env-var values as a list, I would assume cmake has a similar option. Good luck.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you want to know the value of a specific variable, you can use `$ENV{varname}`:

```
message(STATUS $ENV{PATH})
```

If you want to see **all** variables, you probably need to resort to invoking an external command such as `env` (on Unix) or `set` (on Windows):

```
# Windows
execute_process(COMMAND cmd /c set OUTPUT_VARIABLE output)
message(${output})
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to get `cmake` to show output to a console, but if you don't mind just getting it out of a file later, you can add:

```
env > /tmp/environment
```

in the appropriate place, and then read the `/tmp/environment` file later.